# what is inside your $PYTHONPATH?

Tags: ros, gazebo, python, gazebo-simulator, rospkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to find a solution for the problem I have with this error message:

import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg

Can somebody tell me what it should be inside the $PYTHONPATH exactly?
For me it is only : /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40188/what-is-inside-your-$pythonpath?/) by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't provide any information about the platform you are using,how you installed ROS and which version you are using (see [the support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support)) so I assume you installed from Debian packages and you use Fuerte.

The debian package that contains rospkg is `python-rospkg` and the corresponding files are put into /usr/share/pyshared which is a system directory. That means that you don't need to add it to the python path since that's one of the default locations python searches for modules.

Did you install python-rospkg:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
```

Normally, the package should be installed automatically since it is a dependency of ROS. If it's not there, I'm sure something went wrong with your ROS installation.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on 2012-08-01**:
I checked that one too. Finally I erased my Ubuntu 12.0.4 and re-installed Ubuntu 12.0.4 and ROS again. Everything works fine now. Knocking the wood!!